# To set blinking effect on button in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

my requirement is I want to set blink effect on button2 when button1 is clicked.
I did refer this example for blinking effect on textblock.

[Blinking TextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652831/wpf-blinking-textblock)?

but its not working for my button2.
I can show you xaml code if you want.
plz help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <Button Name="button1" Margin="10" Content="Animate Button2!">
    <Button.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="button2" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
              <ColorAnimation From="Black" To="Red" Duration="0:0:1"/>
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
      </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
  </Button>

  <Button Name="button2" Margin="10" Content="I will get animated!"></Button>
```

In case you want to animate the Background: 
This is not that easy to achieve as the framework is using the background for internal stuff, e.g. the hover animation.

See
[Blinking button on WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978183/blinking-button-on-wpf-application)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the button blink on load instead of click on another button then give it a try to this code.

```
<Button Name="btnAlert" Background="DarkRed" Content="Amimation is working!" Foreground="White" FontSize="17">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="btnNewVersionAlert" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                         <ColorAnimation From="Black" To="White" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Button.Triggers></Button>
```