# WPF Jumping or Flashing Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got a hidden button and when if condition is true,  the button is visible to the user. But I want to get user attention to the button so wanted to button to jump or flash on/off for few seconds.

I have seen a few examples but they all triggered by mouseover event.
I tried to replace the event trigger with Data Trigger but didn't accept it.

Does anyone have a similar code or different idea of how to do it, please?

```
 <Button Visibility="{Binding IsVisibleBtnCopyFromPreviousPriceList}" x:Name="BtnCopyProducts" Click="BtnCopyProductsist_Click" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="17" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" FontSize="16" Margin="0"  Height="70" Width="70" Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="Transparent" >
 <StackPanel>
       <Image Source="Images/File_copy_64.png" Width="56" Height="56" />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: [**Maybe**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257091/to-set-blinking-effect-on-button-in-xaml) of use and or help you get a head start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into animations?  They are quite simple to make.  I use the `DoubleAnimation` class to achieve something similar on one of my projects to display a message to the user for a few seconds that things are syncing in the background.

Here's how I do it:

First I create a Storyboard

```
Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
```

Then I create a couple `DoubleAnimation`s.  One that stays solid for a few seconds and one that fades out over a couple seconds.  Here's the fading one:

```
DoubleAnimation fadeAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
fadeAnim.From = 1.0;
fadeAnim.To = 0.0;
fadeAnim.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
fadeAnim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

Finally the animations get added to the `Storyboard`:

```
myStoryboard.Children.Add(fadeAnim);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(fadeAnim, WarningGrid.Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeAnim, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.OpacityProperty));
```

And then it's just a matter of hitting play:

```
myStoryboard.Begin(this);
```

While my example is a little bit different than what you are trying to accomplish, you might be able to use it to make a nice smooth and fast pulse with a few of these put together and set real fast.

Comment: Hi & welcome to SO. Perhaps you could improve your answer by giving a specific example of how an animation could help in this case? Otherwise, perhaps a comment would be more appropriate to get more infromation from the OP.