# Making a WPF Label (or other element) flash using animation

Tags: wpf, animation, triggers, datatrigger

I have a label that I only make visible based on one of my ViewModel Properties.  Here is the XAML:

```
<Label  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
        FontSize="24" Width="200" Height="200" >
    <Label.Content >
        Option in the money! 
    </Label.Content>
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OptionInMoney}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>

</Label>
```

I'm not sure this is the best way, but in any case, I'd also like to have the label flashing.  Clearly, I only want it flashing when it is visible.  Can someone point me to some example code, or write a quick example to do this?  I assume I need some sort of trigger, and an animation.  Presumably I also need a trigger when the label is no longer visible so that I stop the animation?

Thanks, 
Dave
P.S.  Is there a good book or site for all these WPF tricks?  Something like the "MFC Answer Book" for those that remember that book.

Comment: Hah - options trading system? :)  Are you familiar with storyboard animations? You could get the behavior you're after by animating the Opacity property on the element - if I get a chance I'll put up an example.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could add a `Storyboard` animation to the `Style.Resources` and start it in the `EnterActions` section of the `DataTrigger`.

A simple `DoubleAnimation` on the `Opacity` should work fine

Something like this:

```
<Label.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="flashAnimation" >
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Style.Resources>

        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OptionInMoney}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="flash" Storyboard="{StaticResource flashAnimation}" />
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="flash"/>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Label.Style>
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Do I need to arrange to stop the animation when the property(OptionInMoney) goes back to false, or will that happen automatically.  I.e. do I need a DataTrigger.ExitActions and if so, how do I set that up?  I mention it, because I saw some discussion in other posts of the animation continuing forever even though it's not visible.  Thanks again.

Comment: yes, It's probably a good idea to stop the animation in `ExitActions`, I have updated the answer with the `StopStoryboard`

Answer (score 5):

StoryBoard is certainly the WPF way, but it can be achieved by a simple code also. Here it goes, to make a label background blink:

**lblTimer** is a Lebel on your form with some text, say, "I AM BLINKING"

This can be applied to any property, as VISIBILITY.

```
// Create a timer.
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
    timer.Start();
}

// The timer's Tick event.
private bool BlinkOn = false;
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (BlinkOn)
    {
        lblTimer.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        lblTimer.Background = Brushes.White;
    }
    else
    {
        lblTimer.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        lblTimer.Background = Brushes.Black;
    }
    BlinkOn = !BlinkOn;
}
```

Comment: Worked well, I use opacity to flicker with a Visibility.Collapsed when use opts to dismiss the flicker element(s) +1

Answer (score 2):

Try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652831/blinking-textblock#). It's called 'Blinking TextBlock' but you can easily swap a `TextBox` for a Label`.

Comment: Avoid link-only-answers. They are susceptible to link-rot.